# How can I switch layers during animation?

Tags: animation, camera, render-layers

I have 3 layers with 3 objects and 3 cameras.

Layer 1: cube + camera1

Layer 2: uv sphere + camera2

Layer 3: torus + camera3

camera1 is active from 1 to 79 frame.

camera2 is active from 80 to 159 frame.

camera3 is active from 160 to 240 frame.

How can I render only

cube in frames 1-79 ;

only uv sphere in frames 80-159 ;

only torus in frames 160-240

????

Comment: see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one

Comment: Have a thorough look at https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1067/228