# How to delete an object in an animation

Tags: animation

How would I delete an object that I no longer need in an animation? I am animating a projectile, but once it's out of view, I don't want my computer to have to process it anymore. Is there any way for me to delete it after I'm done with it?

Comment: Possibly related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/render-borders-related-check-boxes-how-do-they-work

Comment: Animate the renderablity (camera icon) of the object in the outliner; see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1068/1853 and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8678/how-can-i-animate-the-restrict-visibility-property-of-an-object/8680#8680

Answer (score 7):

You can animate the renderability of the object.

Move the mouse over the camera icon on the outliner and set a keyframe (just press <kbd>i</kbd> or right-click and select insert keyframe) then move to the frame where you want the object to disappear, disable renderability by pressing on the camera icon and set a new keyframe.

[image]

Note that the interpolation for visibility is always Constant.

[image]